# ALU with Structural VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, alu

I am trying to create an ALU using structural code in VHDL. The code was originally in Verilog and then I manually changed it all over to VHDL, so that's why I have many separate files...but in theory these should work. The following are the associated codes and files:

--dwl_fulladd code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_fulladd IS
    PORT    (   
            x, y, Cin:      IN STD_LOGIC;
            s, Cout:            OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dwl_fulladd;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF dwl_fulladd IS

BEGIN
    s <= x XNOR y XNOR Cin;
    Cout <= ((x AND y) OR (x AND Cin) OR (y AND Cin));
END Structural;
```

--dwl_4bitadder code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_4bitadder IS
    PORT    (   
            x, y :      IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryin:    IN STD_LOGIC;
            s:              OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryout:   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dwl_4bitadder;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF dwl_4bitadder IS

SIGNAL c : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 1);

COMPONENT dwl_fulladd
    PORT    (   
            x, y, Cin:      IN STD_LOGIC;
            s, Cout:            OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dwl_fulladd;


BEGIN
stage0: dwl_fulladd PORT MAP (carryin, x(0), y(0), s(0), c(1));
stage1: dwl_fulladd PORT MAP (c(1), x(1), y(1), s(1), c(2));
stage2: dwl_fulladd PORT MAP (c(2), x(2), y(2), s(2), c(3));
stage3: dwl_fulladd PORT MAP (c(3), x(3), y(3), s(3), carryout);

END Structural;
```

--dwl_mux2to1 code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_mux2to1 IS
PORT    (   
            x1, x2, s:      IN STD_LOGIC;
            f:                  OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dwl_mux2to1;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF dwl_mux2to1 IS

BEGIN
f <= (((NOT s)AND x1)OR(s AND x2));

END Structural;
```

--dwl_4mux2to1 code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_4mux2to1 IS
PORT    (   
            x0, x1: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            sel:        IN STD_LOGIC;
            f:          OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0));
END dwl_4mux2to1;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF dwl_4mux2to1 IS

COMPONENT dwl_mux2to1 IS
PORT    (   
            x1, x2, s:      IN STD_LOGIC;
            f:                  OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dwl_mux2to1;

BEGIN
stage0: dwl_mux2to1 PORT MAP (sel, x0(0), x1(0), f(0));
stage1: dwl_mux2to1 PORT MAP (sel, x0(1), x1(1), f(1));
stage2: dwl_mux2to1 PORT MAP (sel, x0(2), x1(2), f(2));
stage3: dwl_mux2to1 PORT MAP (sel, x0(3), x1(3), f(3));

END Structural;
```

--dwl_Blogic code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_Blogic IS
PORT    (   
            FS2_in, FS1_in: IN STD_LOGIC;
            B_in:                   IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            Y_out:              OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0));
            
END dwl_Blogic;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF dwl_Blogic IS

BEGIN
PROCESS (FS2_in, FS1_in, B_in)
BEGIN
if FS2_in = '0' AND FS1_in = '0' then
    Y_out <= "0000";
elsif FS2_in = '0' AND FS1_in = '1' then
    Y_out <= B_in;
elsif FS2_in = '1' AND FS1_in = '0' then
    Y_out <= (NOT B_in);
elsif FS2_in = '1' AND FS1_in = '1' then
    Y_out <= "1111";
end if;
END PROCESS;

END Behavioral;
```

-dwl_lu code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_lu IS
PORT    (   
            FS:         IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 1);
            A, B:           IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            lu_out:     OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryout:   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dwl_lu;

ARCHITECTURE Behavioral OF dwl_lu IS

BEGIN
PROCESS (FS, A, B)
BEGIN
if FS = "00" then
    lu_out <= (Not A);
    carryout <= '0';
elsif FS = "01" then
    lu_out <= (A AND B);
    carryout <= '0';
elsif FS = "10" then
    lu_out <= (A OR B);
    carryout <= '0';
elsif FS = "11" then
    lu_out <= (A(3) & A(3) & A(2) & A(1));
    carryout <= A(0);
END if;
END PROCESS;

END Behavioral;
```

--dwl_au code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_au IS
PORT    (   
            FS:         IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0);
            A, B:           IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            au_out:     OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryout:   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dwl_au;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF dwl_au IS

SIGNAL Y: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);

COMPONENT dwl_Blogic IS
PORT    (   
            FS2_in, FS1_in: IN STD_LOGIC;
            B_in:                   IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            Y_out:              OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0));
            
END COMPONENT dwl_Blogic;

COMPONENT dwl_4bitadder IS
PORT    (   
            x, y :      IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryin:    IN STD_LOGIC;
            s:              OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryout:   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dwl_4bitadder;

BEGIN
stage0: dwl_Blogic (FS(2), FS(1), B, Y);
stage1: dwl_4bitadder (FS(0), A, Y, au_out, carryout);

END Structural;
```

--dwl_alu code--

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

ENTITY dwl_alu_vhdl IS
PORT    (   
            FS, A, B:           IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            F:                      OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            Cout:                   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END dwl_alu_vhdl;

ARCHITECTURE Structural OF dwl_alu_vhdl IS

SIGNAL AU, LU: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL AU_C, LU_C: STD_LOGIC;

COMPONENT dwl_au IS
PORT    (   
            FS:         IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 0);
            A, B:           IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            au_out:     OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryout:   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dwl_au;

COMPONENT dwl_lu IS
PORT    (   
            FS:         IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (2 DOWNTO 1);
            A, B:           IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            lu_out:     OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            carryout:   OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dwl_lu;

COMPONENT dwl_4mux2to1 IS
PORT    (   
            x0, x1: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            sel:        IN STD_LOGIC;
            f:          OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT dwl_4mux2to1;

COMPONENT dwl_mux2to1 IS
PORT    (   
            x1, x2, s:      IN STD_LOGIC;
            f:                  OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT dwl_mux2to1;

BEGIN
stage0: dwl_au (FS(2 DOWNTO 0), A, B, AU, AU_C);
stage1: dwl_lu (FS(2 DOWNTO 1), A, B, LU, LU_C);
stage2: dwl_4mux2to1 (FS(3), AU, LU, F);
stage3: dwl_mux2to1 (FS(3), AU_C, LU_C, Cout);

 END Structural;
```

---

This is the truth table for the Logic unit:

[image: truth table for Logic unit]

This is the truth table for the BLogic Unit:

[image: truth table for BLogic unit]

I keep on getting the following errors:

```
Error (10777): VHDL error at nwl_au.vhd(34): expected an architecture     identifier in index.
Error (10346): VHDL error at nwl_au.vhd(34): formal port or parameter "FS2_in" must have actual or default value.
Error (10784): HDL error at nwl_au.vhd(19): see declaration for object "FS2_in".
Error (10346): VHDL error at nwl_au.vhd(34): formal port or parameter "FS1_in" must have actual or default value.
Error (10784): HDL error at nwl_au.vhd(19): see declaration for object "FS1_in".
Error (10346): VHDL error at nwl_au.vhd(34): formal port or parameter "B_in" must have actual or default value.
Error (10784): HDL error at nwl_au.vhd(20): see declaration for object "B_in".
```

These errors are pertaining to the dwl_au poetion of the code.

Could someone help out with this? I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: The use clause `USE ieee.std_logic_signed.all;` isn't needed anywhere in your code. The error messages you present don't reflect Matthew's changes instead errors based on alternative precedence in parsing (not LR(1)), where a standard conforming VHDL tool might have indicated dwl_blogic etc. are not procedure names (declared as components). A cautionary tale to only hand off valid VHDL to a synthesis tool least you be confused by obtuseness out of the ordinary.

Comment: @user1155120 The ISE Simulator from Xilinx gives the same error messages. And the error message from QuestaSim (ModelSim) is not much better: "Prefix (component declaration "dwl_Blogic") of indexed name is not an array."

Comment: Modelsim expects a signal assignment. [Syntactic predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_predicate) (*component_*name)  IEEE Std 1076-2008 11.7 Component instantiation statements. 1.3.2 Syntactic description, *g) If the name of any syntactic category starts with an italicized part, it is equivalent to the category name without the italicized part. The italicized part is intended to convey some semantic information. ...*, it's a declared component name or the reserved word `component` and look ahead 1 would show not a signal assignment nor procedure call. Easy to implement, not use.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things wrong with your code:

i) Your syntax for instantiation is missing the construct `port map`. This

```
stage0: dwl_Blogic (FS(2), FS(1), B, Y);
stage1: dwl_4bitadder  (A, Y, FS(0),  au_out, carryout);
```

Should be this:

```
stage0: dwl_Blogic port map (FS(2), FS(1), B, Y);
stage1: dwl_4bitadder port map  (A, Y, FS(0),  au_out, carryout);
```

And this:

```
stage0: dwl_au (FS(2 DOWNTO 0), A, B, AU, AU_C);
stage1: dwl_lu (FS(2 DOWNTO 1), A, B, LU, LU_C);
stage2: dwl_4mux2to1 ( AU, LU, FS(3), F);
stage3: dwl_mux2to1 (FS(3), AU_C, LU_C, Cout);
```

should be this:

```
stage0: dwl_au port map (FS(2 DOWNTO 0), A, B, AU, AU_C);
stage1: dwl_lu port map (FS(2 DOWNTO 1), A, B, LU, LU_C);
stage2: dwl_4mux2to1 port map ( AU, LU, FS(3), F);
stage3: dwl_mux2to1 port map (FS(3), AU_C, LU_C, Cout);
```

ii) You have two errors caused by your use of *positional association* in your port maps. Basically, the your have not connected the ports correctly. So, for example, this is not connected correctly (I know because it doesn't compile):

```
stage1: dwl_4bitadder (FS(0), A, Y, au_out, carryout);
```

My *guess* (because on the port types) is that you meant this:

```
stage1: dwl_4bitadder (A, Y, FS(0), au_out, carryout);
```

but only you know whether that is correct. However (and this is really important), if you had used *named association* for your port maps, you probably would not have made such an error. So, instead of the above, (baring in mind I don't know your design intent, so may have got these connections wrong) do this:

```
stage1: dwl_4bitadder (x => A, y => Y, carryin => FS(0), s => au_out, carryout => carryout);
```

**Never use positional association for port maps.** It is too error prone, as you code demonstrates.

Comment: Everyplace component instantiation is used there appear to be positional association order errors. See dwl_4bit_adder, dwl_4mux2to1.